# View drawing correctly when changing orientation, but fails on first display

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, landscape

I have a `UIViewController` in iOS 9 that does not draw correctly when the view appears in landscape mode.

However if the view appears in portrait mode, and then is changed to landscape everything is fine.

This happens both on the simulator and devices. I am using Interface Builder to set the heights and constraints of the subviews. I do not do any resizing of frame sizes or updates to constraints in code.

So I tried to force a redraw similar to a change of orientation, but I could not get it to work and I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewControllers, you will need to override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) method to return YES when the app should rotate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```